# graph edit distance (GED) and (non)-isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, similarity

Is it necessary for graph edit distance (GED) between two graphs G1 and G2 that the graphs (G1, G2) are isomorphic?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. Edit distance is defined for any pair of graphs.

Isomorphic graphs are just a very special case: if G1 and G2 are isomorphic, than their edit distance is 0 directly from definition.

Answer (score 0):

For graph edit distance , it can judge whether the two graphs are similar.
For Isomorphic graphs, its GED is 0.

Comment: Please, when giving an answer, try to provide something new that has not already been included in previous answers. This answer is basically the same as the other answer by user voidengine.